# How to get through Heavenhold Tower level 3?

Tags: guardian-tales

This level is another ghost maze.  Is there a way to effect the ghosts so they don't push you as far or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this video:

You can also find more vids and articles on how to solve this problem.
Hope this helps!